# Find box in the image and save as an image cv2

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am new in computer vision, and I want to create a program which helps me to detect box in the image and save as an image.

[image: input image]

[image: output image 1]

[image: output image 2]

and etc...
I tried some code but did not get my desired result.
here is my code and its output.

```
import cv2
# Load iamge, grayscale, adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('image.jpeg')
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)

# Fill rectangular contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Morph open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=4)

# Draw rectangles
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

output:

[image: code output]

Comment: and what's wrong with that output?

Comment: I guess the problem is that you want the inner contours, not only the external. Change the retrieval mode to `RETR_CCOMP` and use the contour `hierarchy` to filter the nested (child) contours.

Comment: @stateMachine thanks for reply. con you explain me little bit about that how i separate all black boxes and save an image.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is simply first remove the outermost white area, that is, make it black so that we can detect the boxes without any issues using the `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` flag as they are not touching. Then we'll just extract the boxes one by one.

To remove the outmost area, I have used the point polygon test of the contours. If the point (1, 1) lies inside or on a contour, it is not drawn and every other contour will be drawn on a new image. From this new image, I have read the box contours and extracted them.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("2lscp.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

Contours = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

newImg = np.zeros(img.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
for Contour in Contours:
    if cv2.pointPolygonTest(Contour, (1, 1), False) == -1:
        cv2.drawContours(newImg, [Contour], -1, 255, 1)

Contours = cv2.findContours(newImg, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
for Contour in Contours:
    [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(Contour)

    cv2.imshow("box extracted", img[y:y+h, x:x+w])
    cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This case seems particularly simple because the image is quasi-binary. Detect the contours of the white regions and select those that have an area like 10 to 15% of the whole image. These are the desired boxes. Then fit a rectangle or rotated rectangle.

No need for additional processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i am confused how i separate all the black boxes from the image and save it.

Comment: @smscattering: why would you need to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

try this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Read input image
img = cv2.imread('hw_data.png')

#convert from BGR to HSV color space
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#apply threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# find contours and get one with area about 180*35
# draw all contours in green and accepted ones in red
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
#area_thresh = 0
min_area = 0.95*180*44
max_area = 1.05*180*44
print(min_area)
print(max_area)
result = img.copy()
i = 1
for c in contours:
#     print(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    # crop region of img using bounding box
    region = result[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    # save region to new image
    print(region.shape,' i ',i)
#     cv2.imwrite("black_region_{0}.png".format(i), region)
    i = i + 1
    if region.shape[0]>70 and region.shape[1]<100:
        cv2.imwrite("black_region_{0}.png".format(i), region)
#         break
#     if area > min_area and area < max_area:
#             cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)
#             break

# save result
# cv2.imwrite("box_found.png", result)

# show images
# cv2.imshow("GRAY", gray)
# cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
# cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: please review [answer]. code dumps are poor answers. discuss the crucial points of your proposed solution, and what makes it different from other answers.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the advice i will do my best 